# How to add a icon on deck.gl Scatterplot map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, scatter-plot, apache-superset, deck.gl

I am new to Superset. I have already developed a map using Deck.gl Scatterplot. I used my database to plot locations on Mapbox, which currently displays each location as dots with default colors. Now, I want to display an icon instead of dots.

I use JavaScript code inside the DATA INTERCEPTOR box like this:

```
data => data.map(d => ({
    ...d,
    iconUrl: "https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/store_2639570?k=1695617505142&log-in=google"
}));
```

Then I add these codes in the TOOLTIP GENERATOR box.

```
d => {
  const name = d.object.extraProps.name; 
  const iconUrl = d.object.icon;

  const tooltipHtml = `
    <div>
      <img src="${iconUrl}" alt="Custom Icon" width="32" height="32" />
      <strong>${name}</strong>
    </div>
  `;

  return tooltipHtml;
}
```

[Already created map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlIIy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your iconUrl doesn't look right, it should be a page that opens an image. Like this one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Windows_Settings_app_icon.png